# RTK query - I am clearly calling one query but for some reason a different one is being actioned

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

As the title says. This is extremely bizarre to me.

I am quite clearly calling the getThisCategory(genre) query from categoriesApi.js, which should be:

'https://kitsu.io/api/edge/anime?filter%5Bcategories%5D=${genre}'

but in my console there is an error that says:

"GET https://kitsu.io/api/edge/Vampire/anime?limit=20  404".

This looks to me like the query from the animeApi.js file, with the genre parameter passed in. I have no idea why it is calling this query instead.

Please can someone help, this is really frustrating.

Files below:

animeApi.js (the query that SHOULDN'T be getting called but is):

```js
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';

const animeApiHeaders = {
    "Accept": "application/vnd.api+json",
    "Content-Type": "application/vnd.api+json",
};

const baseUrl = 'https://kitsu.io/api/edge';

const createRequest = (url) => ({ url, headers: animeApiHeaders });

export const animeApi = createApi({
    reducerPath: 'animeApi',
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl }),
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
        getCategoryOfAnime: builder.query({
            query: (category) =>
                createRequest(`/${category}/anime?limit=20`)
        }),
    })
});

export const { useGetCategoryOfAnimeQuery } = animeApi;
```

categoriesApi.js (the query that SHOULD be getting called):

```js
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';

const categoryHeaders = {
    "Accept": "application/vnd.api+json",
    "Content-Type": "application/vnd.api+json",
};

const baseUrl = 'https://kitsu.io/api/edge';

const createRequest = (url) => ({ url, headers: categoryHeaders });

export const categoriesApi = createApi({
    reducerPath: 'categoriesApi',
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl }),
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
        getAllCategories: builder.query({
            query: () => 
                createRequest(`/categories?page%5Blimit%5D=40`)
        }),
        getThisCategory: builder.query({
            query: (genre) =>
                createRequest(`/anime?filter%5Bcategories%5D=${genre}`)
        }),
    })
});

export const { useGetAllCategoriesQuery, useGetThisCategoryQuery } = categoriesApi;
```

GenrePage.js (only the relevant parts of component):

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { Link, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useGetThisCategoryQuery } from '../../services/categoriesApi';
import { addThisCategory } from './GenrePageSlice';
import CircularProgress from "@mui/material/CircularProgress";
import './GenrePage.css';
import AnimeCard from '../AnimeCard/AnimeCard';

const GenrePage = () => {
    
    const { genre } = useParams();
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const genreData = useSelector((state) => state.genrePage.thisCategory);
    const { data: thisCategory, isFetching } = useGetThisCategoryQuery(genre);

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(addThisCategory(thisCategory));
    }, [thisCategory]);
```

store.js:

```js
import { combineReducers, configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

import { animeApi } from "../services/animeApi";
import { categoriesApi } from "../services/categoriesApi";

import animeBannerReducer from '../components/AnimeBanner/AnimeBannerSlice';
import animeCategoryReducer from "../components/AnimeCategoryPage/AnimeCategoryPageSlice";
import categoriesReducer from '../components/Categories/CategoriesSlice';

export default configureStore({
    reducer: {
        [animeApi.reducerPath]: animeApi.reducer,
        [categoriesApi.reducerPath]: categoriesApi.reducer,
        animeBanner: animeBannerReducer,
        animeCategory: animeCategoryReducer,
        categories: categoriesReducer,
    },
    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware().concat(animeApi.middleware, categoriesApi.middleware),
});
```

App.js:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import "./App.css"

import Header from '../components/Header/Header';
import Homepage from '../components/Homepage/Homepage';
import AnimeCategoryPage from '../components/AnimeCategoryPage/AnimeCategoryPage';
import GenrePage from '../components/GenrePage/GenrePage';

const App = () => {

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <div className="app">
          <Header />
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Homepage />} />
            <Route path="/anime/:category" element={<AnimeCategoryPage />} />
            <Route path="/anime/:genre" element={<GenrePage />} />
          </Routes>
        </div>
    </BrowserRouter>

  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out - I was being stupid.

The issue was with my routes set up in App.js.

Because the GenrePage was being called on the route '/anime/:genre', and the AnimeCategoryPage was being called on '/anime/:category', react-router was always calling the first component on the base '/anime' which was AnimeCategoryPage instead of GenrePage.

Fixed by changing the route for GenrePage to '/explore/:genre'

Answer (score 5):

A bit off-topic, but important enough to put it into an answer to this - in the hopes that someone else will read it in the future too:

**Please do not use that kind of `createRequest` helper function.**
That is taken from a tutorial that grossly misunderstands what `baseQuery` is for.

Essentially, `baseQuery` is already a `createRequest` function like this - the return value of an endpoint's `query` function will be passed as first argument into `baseQuery`, which will in the case of `fetchBaseQuery` then call `fetch`.

So please use `fetchBaseQuery` correctly instead here:

```js
const baseUrl = 'https://kitsu.io/api/edge';

export const categoriesApi = createApi({
    reducerPath: 'categoriesApi',
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ 
      baseUrl,
//    either you can just set `headers` here:
//    headers: categoryHeader

//    or you use `prepareHeaders` where you can do some calulations and have access to stuff like `getState` or the endpoint name
      prepareHeaders: (headers, { getState, endpoint, type, forced }) => {
         headers.set("Accept", "application/vnd.api+json")
         headers.set("Content-Type": "application/vnd.api+json")
         return headers
      }
     }),
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
        getAllCategories: builder.query({
          query: () => { url: `/categories?page%5Blimit%5D=40` }
// or the short notation: if you only have an `url` just pass a string
//        query: () => `/categories?page%5Blimit%5D=40`
        }),
    })
});
```

Also, and that might also be a misconception from that tutorial: you should in almost all cases only have **one** api for your whole application. If you want to split that over multiple files, you can [see the docs on Code Splitting](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/code-splitting)